# Python List of random number with difference of 2 between them

Tags: python, list, random

Help me creating a python list of random numbers between 0 to 100, with every succeeding number having a difference of 2 between them.

Comment: difference of exactly 2 or at least 2?
Can you give a small example?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an Explanation here:
[Create random sequence of integers within a range and with a minimum distance between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948065/create-random-sequence-of-integers-within-a-range-and-with-a-minimum-distance-be)

Just modify these parameters to match your case:

```
n = 5
limit = 20
mingap = 3
slack = 20 - mingap * (n - 1)
```